# Sscanf not reading identical lines the same way

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void printLine(char* line) {
     char lat, lon;
     unsigned int year, month, day;
     float temp, uncertainty, latitude, longitude;
     char country[100], city[100];
     int result;

     result = sscanf(line, "%u-%u-%u,%f,%f,%[^,],%[^,],%f%c,%f%c", &year,
         &month,&day, &temp, &uncertainty, city, country, &latitude, &lat, &longitude, &lon);

     printf("%u-%u-%u,%f,%f,%s,%s,%f%c,%f%c\n", year, month, day, temp, uncertainty,
         city, country, latitude, lat, longitude, lon);

     printf("sscanf read %i variables\n", result);
}
int main() {
    char line[] = "2013-08-01,19.005,3.621,Addis Abeba,Ethiopia,8.84N,38.11E";
    char line2[] = "1816-03-01,27.426,1.793,Bangkok,Thailand,13.66N,99.91E";
    char line3[] = "1743-11-01,3.264,1.665,New York,United States,40.99N,74.56W";

    printLine(line);
    printLine(line2);
    printLine(line3);
}
```

Some lines it reads properly and some lines it doesn't read the last character. I'm not sure what causes this bug, I'm probably invoking some sort of undefined behaviour but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: @user3121023 so what am I supposed to do to fix that?

Comment: ... and of course, the matter of reading a line at a time or not is orthogonal to the matter of using input field directives that won't match the trailing 'E' in your longitudes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the `E` is being read as part of the float.  You can use this code to read the float as a string and then convert it to a float:

```
void printLine(char* line) {
    char lat, lon;
    unsigned int year, month, day;
    float temp, uncertainty;
    char latitude[100], longitude[100];
    float latFloat, longFloat;
    char country[100], city[100];
    char blah[100];
    int result;
    result = sscanf(line, "%u-%u-%u,%f,%f,%[^,],%[^,],%[0-9.]%c,%[0-9.]%c", &year,
        &month, &day, &temp, &uncertainty, city, country, latitude, &lat, longitude, &lon);

    latFloat = atof(latitude);
    longFloat = atof(longitude);

    printf("%u-%u-%u,%f,%f,%s,%s,%f%c,%f%c\n", year, month, day, temp, uncertainty,
        city, country, latFloat, lat, longFloat, lon);

    printf("sscanf read %i variables\n", result);
}
```